# Which SQL formula can I use to find the average of two columns and then add those together?

Tags: sql, formula, average

I would like to find the average of two columns of data that have numerical information so that I can add those together.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: Please take one of two options before creating a question here: 1) Read documentations for such general and simple questions or 2) Provide detailed information (sample data, expected result etc.) if you don't find a solution on your own. Thanks.

Comment: select avg(col1 + col2) from tablename, or, if null values are involvde, select avg(col1) + avg(col2) from tablename.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.